# How can I change wifi DNS setting iOS using swift

Tags: ios, swift, networking, dns, settings

I am trying my best to get this working.

I have a DNS server for my clients where sometimes I send them emails to chnage their DNS Settings. But now I want to do that via an ios app. 
is there a way I can let them download the app and click one button on the app that will chnage it ?

I looked at this 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkExtension/Reference/NEDNSSettingsClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NEDNSSettings

but unsure

THanks

Comment: No, the sandbox prevents (quite rightly) an app from making changes to network settings.

Comment: what about this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkExtension/Reference/NEDNSSettingsClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NEDNSSettings

Comment: Yes you can do that if you are creating a VPN configuration for your client, but it doesn't affect the non-VPN network settings of the device https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkExtension/Reference/Network_Extension_Framework_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016234

Comment: Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025200/how-to-change-add-dns-server-for-connected-wifi-in-ios-programmatically), it is hacky, but works.

Comment: I am not seeing an answer. Was it deleted? @Popmedic

Comment: It is still there.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Network Extensions classes.  With the [NETunnelProviderManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/netunnelprovidermanager) class you can set the [onDemandRules](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1406862-ondemandrules) with a [NEEvaluateConnectionRule](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neevaluateconnectionrule).  The [NEEvaluateConnectionRule constructor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neevaluateconnectionrule/1406315-init) can take a list of wildcard with top-level-domains (i.e. `["*.com", "*.net", "*.org", "*.io"]`) as the domains, and use [NEEvaluateConnectionRuleAction.connectIfNeeded](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neevaluateconnectionruleaction/1406204-connectifneeded) as the action.  Set the [onDemandRules](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1406862-ondemandrules) of the [NEEvaluateConnectionRule](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neevaluateconnectionrule) you create with all tlds as the domains.  Then create a [NEOnDemandRuleEvaluateConnection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neondemandruleevaluateconnection) and set its [connectionRules](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neondemandruleevaluateconnection/1405987-connectionrules) to the [NEEvaluateConnectionRule](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neevaluateconnectionrule) created with all of the top-level-domains, and set its [interfaceTypeMatch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neondemandrule/1406433-interfacetypematch) to [NEOnDemandRuleInterfaceType.any](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neondemandruleinterfacetype/1406175-any).  Set the [NETunnelProviderManager.onDemandRules](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1406862-ondemandrules) with a [NEOnDemandRuleEvaluateConnection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neondemandruleevaluateconnection) created this way.  If you create a [NETunnelProviderManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/netunnelprovidermanager)and [load it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1406177-loadfrompreferences) and [save it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1405985-savetopreferences) as described above, you can then turn it on and off by using the [NETunnelProviderManager.isEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1406382-isenabled) and [NETunnelProviderManager.isOnDemandEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1406200-isondemandenabled) properties.

Here is an example class that does exactly that.

```
import Foundation
import NetworkExtension

public class VPNConnect {
    private static let vpnDescription = "DNS OnDemand to GoogleDNS"
    private static let vpnServerDescription = "OnDemand DNS to GoogleDNS"

    public var manager:NETunnelProviderManager = NETunnelProviderManager()
    public var dnsEndpoint1:String = "8.8.8.8"
    public var dnsEndpoint2:String = "8.8.4.4"

    public var connected:Bool {
        get {
            return self.manager.isOnDemandEnabled
        }
        set {
            if newValue != self.connected {
                update(
                    body: {
                        self.manager.isEnabled = newValue
                        self.manager.isOnDemandEnabled = newValue

                    },
                    complete: {
                        if newValue {
                            do {
                                try (self.manager.connection as? NETunnelProviderSession)?.startVPNTunnel(options: nil)
                            } catch let err as NSError {
                                NSLog("\(err.localizedDescription)")
                            }
                        } else {
                            (self.manager.connection as? NETunnelProviderSession)?.stopVPNTunnel()
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }

    public init() {
        refreshManager()
    }

    public func refreshManager() -> Void {
        NETunnelProviderManager.loadAllFromPreferences(completionHandler: { (managers, error) in
            if nil == error {
                if let managers = managers {
                    for manager in managers {
                        if manager.localizedDescription == VPNConnect.vpnDescription {
                            self.manager = manager
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            self.setPreferences()
        })
    }

    private func update(body: @escaping ()->Void, complete: @escaping ()->Void) {
        manager.loadFromPreferences { error in
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog("Load error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                return
            }            
            body()
            self.manager.saveToPreferences { (error) in
                if nil != error {
                    NSLog("vpn_connect: save error \(error!)")
                } else {
                    complete()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func setPreferences() {
        self.manager.localizedDescription = VPNConnect.vpnDescription        
        let proto = NETunnelProviderProtocol()
        proto.providerBundleIdentifier = "com.popmedic.vpntunnel.provider"
        proto.serverAddress = VPNConnect.vpnServerDescription
        self.manager.protocolConfiguration = proto
        // TLDList is a struct I created in its own swift file that has an array of all top level domains
        let evaluationRule = NEEvaluateConnectionRule(matchDomains: TLDList.tlds, 
                                                         andAction: NEEvaluateConnectionRuleAction.connectIfNeeded)
        evaluationRule.useDNSServers = [self.dnsEndpoint1, self.dnsEndpoint2]
        let onDemandRule = NEOnDemandRuleEvaluateConnection()
        onDemandRule.connectionRules = [evaluationRule]
        onDemandRule.interfaceTypeMatch = NEOnDemandRuleInterfaceType.any
        self.manager.onDemandRules = [onDemandRule]
    }
}
```

Please note that you will have to turn the Network Extensions capabilities on and there will be a dialog presented telling the user that you are turning on a VPN connection, but you will not have the [VPN] icon in the status bar when the connection is turned on because we are not setting a vpn, just using the on demand rules.

Hate Google as much as I do, maybe use this for the DNS you set...
[Quad9](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/11/new-quad9-dns-service-blocks-malicious-domains-for-everyone/)

Comment: Thanks. What's the matchDomains rule to use everything?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not way to do `*.*` wildcards for the matchDomains, so I created an array (TLDList.tlds) that has `*.<tld>` for all top level domains, and pass that in.

Comment: Here is a gist of what I used: https://gist.github.com/popmedic/cf9472aa8c2adda875a484c5a1c5da06

Comment: Hey, thanks for the code but I am getting this error:
`vpn_connect: save error Error Domain=NEVPNErrorDomain Code=1 "Missing protocol or protocol has invalid type" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing protocol or protocol has invalid type}` 
how can Fix this ?

Comment: **Please note that you will have to turn on the Network Extensions capabilities**. Have you turned them on?

Comment: @Popmedic, I am getting this error can you please help?
`The operation couldn’t be completed. (NEVPNErrorDomain error 1.)`. I have configured with the DNS addresses still it saying configuration error.

Comment: I have implemented the solution and turned on the Network Extensions capabilities but getting error: Error Domain=NEVPNErrorDomain Code=1 "Missing protocol or protocol has invalid type"

Answer (score 0):

Please consider building a DNSProxy Extension(one of the Network Extension) to intercept all DNS traffic generated on a device and use custom/Internal DNS servers.