# How to change/add DNS server for connected WiFi in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, dns

I want to change/add DNS server for connected WiFi of my iPhone device in iOS programmatically?

The Google Public DNS IP addresses (IPv4) are as follows:
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4

I want to change/add it as like in attached screenshot programmatically.

Please help. I can manage whether its in Objective-c or Swift. It will be more helpful for me in Objective-c.
Thanks in advance.

Dummy/Old DNS server of connected Wi-Fi:-

[image]

Required DNS server of connected Wi-Fi:-

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do that. iOS will not allow it unless your phone is jailbroken.

Comment: No, its not jailbroken. Actually I am using Twilio service and calling is not working with dummy DNS. It is working with Google Public DNS. So I want to programmatically change it. If not, then any other idea so I can implement it properly. Thanks.

Comment: That's the beauty of iOS - it does not allow any old apps to mess with network settings. So you cannot do it except for jailbroken devices.

Comment: Lies I tell you, Lies.  It is possible with Network Extensions.  See below.

Comment: Reading your whole comment, I think you need to know something.  The WiFi you connect to will set your DNS if you are not over-riding it with a VPN or DNS proxy.  It is probably just the DNS your WiFi is setting that doesn't like Twilio (I assume you are trying to use Twilio VoIP.)  The WiFi is probably using their DNS to block VoIP (VoIP is a bandwidth hog.) Without more information I can not offer a "proper" solution, but my answer below will over-ride the WiFi set DNS and work, but EXTREMELY hacky (if that is a word.)

Answer (score 8):

Look at the Network Extensions classes.  With the [NETunnelProviderManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/netunnelprovidermanager) class you can set the [onDemandRules](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1406862-ondemandrules) with a [NEEvaluateConnectionRule](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neevaluateconnectionrule).  The [NEEvaluateConnectionRule constructor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neevaluateconnectionrule/1406315-init) can take a list of wildcard with top-level-domains (i.e. `["*.com", "*.net", "*.org", "*.io"]`) as the domains, and use [NEEvaluateConnectionRuleAction.connectIfNeeded](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neevaluateconnectionruleaction/1406204-connectifneeded) as the action.  Set the [onDemandRules](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1406862-ondemandrules) of the [NEEvaluateConnectionRule](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neevaluateconnectionrule) you create with all tlds as the domains.  Then create a [NEOnDemandRuleEvaluateConnection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neondemandruleevaluateconnection) and set its [connectionRules](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neondemandruleevaluateconnection/1405987-connectionrules) to the [NEEvaluateConnectionRule](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neevaluateconnectionrule) created with all of the top-level-domains, and set its [interfaceTypeMatch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neondemandrule/1406433-interfacetypematch) to [NEOnDemandRuleInterfaceType.any](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neondemandruleinterfacetype/1406175-any).  Set the [NETunnelProviderManager.onDemandRules](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1406862-ondemandrules) with a [NEOnDemandRuleEvaluateConnection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neondemandruleevaluateconnection) created this way.  If you create a [NETunnelProviderManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/netunnelprovidermanager)and [load it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1406177-loadfrompreferences) and [save it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1405985-savetopreferences) as described above, you can then turn it on and off by using the [NETunnelProviderManager.isEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1406382-isenabled) and [NETunnelProviderManager.isOnDemandEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1406200-isondemandenabled) properties.

Here is an example class that does exactly that.

```
import Foundation
import NetworkExtension

public class VPNConnect {
    private static let vpnDescription = "DNS OnDemand to GoogleDNS"
    private static let vpnServerDescription = "OnDemand DNS to GoogleDNS"

    public var manager:NETunnelProviderManager = NETunnelProviderManager()
    public var dnsEndpoint1:String = "8.8.8.8"
    public var dnsEndpoint2:String = "8.8.4.4"

    public var connected:Bool {
        get {
            return self.manager.isOnDemandEnabled
        }
        set {
            if newValue != self.connected {
                update(
                    body: {
                        self.manager.isEnabled = newValue
                        self.manager.isOnDemandEnabled = newValue

                    },
                    complete: {
                        if newValue {
                            do {
                                try (self.manager.connection as? NETunnelProviderSession)?.startVPNTunnel(options: nil)
                            } catch let err as NSError {
                                NSLog("\(err.localizedDescription)")
                            }
                        } else {
                            (self.manager.connection as? NETunnelProviderSession)?.stopVPNTunnel()
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }

    public init() {
        refreshManager()
    }
    
    public func refreshManager() -> Void {
        NETunnelProviderManager.loadAllFromPreferences(completionHandler: { (managers, error) in
            if nil == error {
                if let managers = managers {
                    for manager in managers {
                        if manager.localizedDescription == VPNConnect.vpnDescription {
                            self.manager = manager
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            self.setPreferences()
        })
    }
    
    private func update(body: @escaping ()->Void, complete: @escaping ()->Void) {
        manager.loadFromPreferences { error in
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog("Load error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                return
            }            
            body()
            self.manager.saveToPreferences { (error) in
                if nil != error {
                    NSLog("vpn_connect: save error \(error!)")
                } else {
                    complete()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func setPreferences() {
        self.manager.localizedDescription = VPNConnect.vpnDescription        
        let proto = NETunnelProviderProtocol()
        proto.providerBundleIdentifier = "com.popmedic.vpntunnel.provider"
        proto.serverAddress = VPNConnect.vpnServerDescription
        self.manager.protocolConfiguration = proto
        // TLDList is a struct I created in its own swift file that has an array of all top level domains
        let evaluationRule = NEEvaluateConnectionRule(matchDomains: TLDList.tlds, 
                                                         andAction: NEEvaluateConnectionRuleAction.connectIfNeeded)
        evaluationRule.useDNSServers = [self.dnsEndpoint1, self.dnsEndpoint2]
        let onDemandRule = NEOnDemandRuleEvaluateConnection()
        onDemandRule.connectionRules = [evaluationRule]
        onDemandRule.interfaceTypeMatch = NEOnDemandRuleInterfaceType.any
        self.manager.onDemandRules = [onDemandRule]
    }
}
```

Please note that you will have to turn the Network Extensions capabilities on and there will be a dialog presented telling the user that you are turning on a VPN connection, but you will not have the [VPN] icon in the status bar when the connection is turned on because we are not setting a vpn, just using the on demand rules.

[Here is the TLDList class I used.](https://gist.github.com/popmedic/cf9472aa8c2adda875a484c5a1c5da06)

Hate Google as much as I do, maybe use this for the DNS you set...
[Quad9](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/11/new-quad9-dns-service-blocks-malicious-domains-for-everyone/)

### Update for iOS 14

In iOS 14 they have added a [NEDNSSettingsManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nednssettingsmanager) that will allow setting the DNS.

Comment: is there any way to get DNS nameserver IP Address of connected network?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256024/get-dns-server-ip-from-iphone-settings