# Retrieving DNS configuration in an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, dns

How can I retrieve the current DNS configuration (servers, search domains, etc) from an iOS app?

The SystemConfiguration framework seems like almost what I want, except almost the entire framework is unavailable on iOS. The only things that are available seem to be functions to get a list of Wi-Fi networks.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025200/how-to-change-add-dns-server-for-connected-wifi-in-ios-programmatically

Comment: @D.3 that covers how to change the dns configuration, not how to retrieve the current dns configuration