# How to configure the DNS settings programmatically in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, networking, dns, settings

I am trying to change the DNS settings to use the Google DNS servers from my code,
I searched a lot and found this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50730387/4949756 from @user3769499 question, but it doesn't work for me.
This is my code:

```
import Foundation
import NetworkExtension

public class VPNConnect {
    public static let shared: VPNConnect = VPNConnect()
    
    private static let vpnDescription = "DNS OnDemand to GoogleDNS"
    private static let vpnServerDescription = "OnDemand DNS to GoogleDNS"

    public var manager:NETunnelProviderManager = NETunnelProviderManager()
    public var dnsEndpoint1:String = "8.8.8.8"
    public var dnsEndpoint2:String = "8.8.4.4"

    public var connected:Bool {
        get {
            return self.manager.isOnDemandEnabled
        }
        set {
            if newValue != self.connected {
                update(
                    body: {
                        self.manager.isEnabled = newValue
                        self.manager.isOnDemandEnabled = newValue

                    },
                    complete: {
                        if newValue {
                            do {
                                try (self.manager.connection as? NETunnelProviderSession)?.startVPNTunnel(options: nil)
                            } catch let err as NSError {
                                NSLog("\(err.localizedDescription)")
                            }
                        } else {
                            (self.manager.connection as? NETunnelProviderSession)?.stopVPNTunnel()
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }

    public init() {
        refreshManager()
    }

    public func refreshManager() -> Void {
        NETunnelProviderManager.loadAllFromPreferences(completionHandler: { (managers, error) in
            if nil == error {
                if let managers = managers {
                    for manager in managers {
                        if manager.localizedDescription == VPNConnect.vpnDescription {
                            self.manager = manager
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            self.setPreferences()
        })
    }

    private func update(body: @escaping ()->Void, complete: @escaping ()->Void) {
        manager.loadFromPreferences { error in
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog("Load error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                return
            }
            body()
            self.manager.saveToPreferences { (error) in
                if nil != error {
                    NSLog("vpn_connect: save error \(error!)")
                } else {
                    complete()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func setPreferences() {
        self.manager.localizedDescription = VPNConnect.vpnDescription
        let proto = NETunnelProviderProtocol()
//        proto.providerBundleIdentifier = "com.DNSTest.NetworkExt"
        proto.serverAddress = VPNConnect.vpnServerDescription
        self.manager.protocolConfiguration = proto
        // TLDList is a struct I created in its own swift file that has an array of all top level domains
        let evaluationRule = NEEvaluateConnectionRule(matchDomains: TLDList.tlds,
                                                         andAction: NEEvaluateConnectionRuleAction.connectIfNeeded)
        evaluationRule.useDNSServers = [self.dnsEndpoint1, self.dnsEndpoint2]
        let onDemandRule = NEOnDemandRuleEvaluateConnection()
        onDemandRule.connectionRules = [evaluationRule]
        onDemandRule.interfaceTypeMatch = NEOnDemandRuleInterfaceType.any
        self.manager.onDemandRules = [onDemandRule]
    }
}
```

But now, I have two questions.

1. where should I put this class? Should it be in the main app target, or create a `NetworkExtension` target and put this class inside it?
2. If I have to make the `NetworkExtension` target, how can I access this class to enable/disable the DNS?

Comment: Hi did you find any solution for this ? I am also facing same kind of issues.

Comment: @superGokuN Unfortunately no